# Клавиша Shift не срабатывает при последовательном вводе открывающей и закрывающей фигурной скобки

Tags: клавиатура, железо, ввод

Ноутбук с Win10, встроенная клавиатура работает нормально. На подключаемой Defender Nova SM-680L после быстрого ввода одинарной фигурной скобки на русском или английском клавиша Shift не срабатывает.

Т.е. если печатать медленно, идет нормальный ввод `{}, }{, ХЪ, ЪХ`, а если быстро, то `{]}, ХъЪ, ЪхХ, }[{`. Причем, если печатать открывающие двойные скобки, то всё нормально: {{}}. Остальные клавиши также печатаются штатно. Действие распространяется именно на эти две клавиши

Драйвер от ноутбука переустанавливал. Понятно, что дело в клавиатуре, но что за дело?

Comment: В каком-то определённом редакторе? Или во всех случаях ввода текста?

Comment: Если вы в Windows, то отыщите "специальные возможности клавиатуры" / "accessibility/keyboard" и запретите там всё.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy везде, всё запретил :( Не пойму даже как это на аппаратном уровне может работать - прерывания накладываются?